# Can't INSERT data to database

Tags: java, mysql, database, insert

trying to insert data to mySQL database and I get this following error

> "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1"

```
 private void insertCourse(){
    String query = "INSERT INTO courses(id,name,price,start,end) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {
        Connection conn = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        stmt.setString(1,this.tfId.getText());
        stmt.setString(2,this.tfName.getText());
        stmt.setString(3,this.tfPrice.getText());
        stmt.setString(4,this.tfStart.getEditor().getText());
        stmt.setString(5,this.tfEnd.getEditor().getText());

        executeQuery(query);
        showCourses();

    } catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: id and price is string?
please copy&past the query string after all setters

Comment: Could it be that `id` and probably `price` are not strings?? Use `setInt(1, this.tfId.getText());` for id field for example

Comment: Yes my bad, id and price is not string, but what syntax to use now ? because if I write setInt(1, this.tfId.getText()); its shows me error

Comment: Or that `id` is a generated identity column and won’t accept direct inserts?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(this.tfId.getText());` will convert that to an `int` for you.

Comment: No id is set by me it 's not generated

Comment: Integer.parseInt(this.tfId.getText()); same error...